# Laravel 5.5, error when the database row is null on paginate: Call to a member function paginate() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel-5.5

I have written some code to show a crud table with some internet radio stations, I want to show the first created internet radio stations to show as the first item or the number one in the table.

The code works when there's at least one internet radio station in the database, but doesn't work on null.

I have written the following code in the controller:

```
$internetradiostations = Internetradiostations::first()->paginate(5);
    return view('internetradiostationsviewer',
        compact('internetradiostations'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1 ) *5); `
```

When executing i get the following error when there's no internet radio station in the database: 
Call to a member function paginate() on null

Strangely the code still works on null and doen't give errors when using 
`Internetradiostations::latest()->paginate(5);`
instead of:
`Internetradiostations::first()->paginate(5);`

Comment: Just a side note: It's convention to keep your model names singular, as one model represents *one internet radio station*, not *more internet radio stations*

Comment: Might want to take a look at `firstOrFail()`

Comment: @Dencker I will keep that in mind, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to paginate data with a single element. Just keep-

```
$internetradiostations = Internetradiostations::first();
```

If you want to paginate then remove `first()`-

```
$internetradiostations = Internetradiostations::paginate(5);
```